# Error: API graphic version incompatible in R

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

I am using R Studio 1.0.44 and R 3.3.3 in Ubuntu 16.04. Tried to execute a simple plot but it is showing the following message:

> Error: API graphic version incompatible

I installed the devtools XML2 and RVG but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update to [RStudio v1.0.153 or later](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) to resolve this.